# About Compression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a question about compression algorithm. So softwares like winzip are meant to compress files my question is ,How can I compress web based application so that it could take less amount and how much cloud based companies compress user's files?

Comment: What do you mean by "compress web-based application"? And less amount of _what_?

Comment: Less amount of space and I'm talking about lossless compression.

Comment: So you want to compress application code/binaries? To what end, specifically? Deployment artifacts (code or binaries) usually take up maaaybe couple dozens megabytes, which is trivial by modern standards. If you're about compressing _data_ (as in, databases or other user-generated content) -- that's a totally different question.

Comment: I agree with @AntonGogolev; a little more specificity of what exactly you are trying to achieve would help...

Comment: You can compress anything for storage purposes (using literally any compression algorithm). If you're talking about compression which would allow active usage, that's partially / sometimes possible, but that's an entirely different question and would still be hopelessly too broad to be appropriate here.

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry for my unclarified question I'm asking that some web pages having high-resolution images & videos take a bit more time to display but can I compress the size of the images and videos so that they can be as fast as paragraphs & headings.Is there anyway?                           And yes I'm talking about application code.                                          
My next question is what application is used by cloud companies use to compress data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What most people use for web based apps is minification. It works by compiling the css, javascript and other scripts to a minified version (it's different from compression). These minified files save memory and load much faster.

Here is a really simple explanation on minification: https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary/minification/

Here is a stack exchange question that explains the difference between minification and compression: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232586/what-is-the-real-difference-between-a-minified-and-uncompressed-file-what-are-t

Comment: Thanx man really helpful

Answer (score 0):

One way to compress your web application files (PHP/HTML/CSS/etc.) is to minify them.

This can turn something that's like 125 kb down to, say 50 kb etc. (just an example... what it ends up compressing down to, all depends)